# Can't delete a media file on android phone with AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

[Check the last edit in the second half for updates about the main issue]

My phone stores its pictures on the SD card. I use the `CameraUI` to take a picture and then I would like to analyse and delete it.

Code (simplified):

```
private function startCapture():void
{
    _camera = new CameraUI();
    _camera.addEventListener( MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onCapture );

    _camera.launch(MediaType.IMAGE); //works fine
}


private function onCapture(e:MediaEvent):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();

    _filePromise = e.data;
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onAsyncMediaComplete);
    loader.loadFilePromise(m__filePromise);
}


private function onAsyncMediaComplete(e:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = (e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).loader; 
    //here the loader contains the picture as expected

    //FIXME adds an empty picture instead of deleting
    _filePromise.file.deleteFile();
}
```

I expect the picture on the SD card to be removed, but instead it's still there and a new dummy file is created next to it.
I traced the file's URL and got `storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20131016_204700.jpg`

My android manifest includes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

EDIT:

As seen on [this article](http://flashvisions.com/air/workaround-for-adobe-air-saving-2-duplicate-copies-of-image-using-cameraui/comment-page-1/#comment-16461), AIR creates two pictures, one in `DCIM/Camera` and one in `DCIM/100MEDIA`. As suggested, I scanned DCIM's subfolders for pictures with the same timestamp (+- 3 seconds) and the same size as `event.data.file`. And then delete these two pictures. Here is the code:

```
var date:Date = m__filePromise.file.modificationDate;
var size:Number = m__filePromise.file.size;
trace("looking for", date.time, size);
var cameraFolder:File = m__filePromise.file.parent.parent;
var pictureFolders:/*File*/Array = cameraFolder.getDirectoryListing();
var pictures:/*File*/Array;
for each(var folder:File in pictureFolders)
{
    pictures = folder.getDirectoryListing();
    for each(var pic:File in pictures)
    {
        if (pic.size == size &&
            Math.abs(pic.modificationDate.time - date.time) < 3000)
        {
            //approximatively the same date, same size, let's delete the copy
            trace("delete", pic.modificationDate.time, pic.size, pic.name);
            pic.deleteFile();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `deleteFile` doesn't work, it leaves an empty file (0b) with the same name. I've read its a cache issue and the only workarounds I've found are for native code.

Comment: Do you get any error when doing it? I'm assuming it is a sandbox violation on the adobe air side if the file that you are trying to delete is not directly under the sandboxed folders. Even with the manifest permissions, it might not work.

Comment: Nope, no error at all. Is there a way I could modify the sandboxed folder? Oh I've figured out something and edited my question.

Comment: Are you listening to the complete event to delete the file? normally in on capture handler you can get the file reference of the file that is captured (e.data as MediaPromise).file and  delete that file  by calling deleteFile() on the file itself. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/MediaPromise.html

Comment: That's exactly what my code does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its a cache issue with media files on Android in General. You would have to find a way how to launch the Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED or some other way how to refresh the MediaStore of the device (Native extension maybe)

Another solution would be to use the Camera class and take the photo directly in your app. This is a minimalist way how you can take a picture directly in your app

```
    private var _video : Video;
    private var _cameraImage : Bitmap;
    private var _camera : Camera;

    /**
     * initilize camera
     */
    private function initCamera() : void {

        //get camera
        _camera = getCamera(CameraPosition.FRONT);
        _camera.setMode(_streamW, _streamH, streamFPS, true);
        _camera.setQuality(0, 100);
        _camPosition = CameraPosition.FRONT;

         //camera preview
        _video = new Video(_streamW, _streamH);
        _video.attachCamera(_camera);


        //rotate        
        var m : Matrix = new Matrix();
        m.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        m.translate(_video.height, 0);
        this._video.transform.matrix = m;
        addChild(_video);
    }

    /**
     * takes photo and saves to bitmap
     */
    private function onTakePhoto(event : GestureEvent) : void {     
        var cameraBitmap : BitmapData = new BitmapData(_streamH, _streamW, true, 0x0);
        cameraBitmap.draw(_video, _video.transform.matrix);
        _cameraImage = new Bitmap(cameraBitmap);
    }

    /**
     * finds camera in desired position
     */
    private function getCamera(position : String) : Camera {
        for (var i : uint = 0; i < Camera.names.length; ++i) {
            var cam : Camera = Camera.getCamera(String(i));
            if (cam.position == position) return cam;
        }
        return Camera.getCamera();
    }
```

If you take your photo directly in your app you will loose lot of the features of the native photo app but will have full control when manipulating and saving the image and also can provide a custom interface specific for your app. You can also try this native extension http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#camera which let's you use some more advanced features of the camera directly in the app.

Comment: Using the Camera class is the alternative I've considered but I hate it since I want my screen orientation to remain automatic. Correct me but your `m.rotate(Math.PI / 2)` only works in portrait mode and the video preview will be rotated.
I am not very confortable with Native Extension, if you could point me a simple way to implement what you are talking about I may validate your answer.

Comment: The rotation was in my case to rotate the camera preview to landscape mode. So you probably could implement auto rotation, by listening to the rotate event and then changing the settings of the camera resolution and rotating the video preview when in landscape mode. But I understand that you prefer the CameraUI solution. Creating a native extension especially setting up the environment and building takes some work but you have the advantage that you need just one platform this is a pretty good [tutorial here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html).

Comment: Just to document my hate for the Camera class, it deactivate the autofocus. You have to recreate the object every now and then to allow the focus to adapt (and it closes/reopens the shutter, which may not be very good for the camera).